# How to determine the minimum grid length | Numerical Plasma physics

Tags: python-3.x, physics

I am learning particle-in-cell (PIC) python code. PIC currently represents one of the most important plasma simulation tools. It is particularly suited to the study of kinetic or non-Maxwellian effects.

Given the following dispersion relation

[image]

I found the range of wave numbers k for which the oscillation frequency is imaginary to be -|\frac{w}{v_0}| < k < |\frac{w}{v_0}|

What I am trying to understand is how to find the minimum grid length L_{min} as a function of \frac{v_0}{w}. L_{min} indicates the needed minimum grid length to support such unstable modes.

I think we should be able to study the plasma behaviour for both L < L_{min} and L > L_{min}. I was told I should adjust the number of simulation particles to grid points to improve the statistics. Besides, the number of particles per cell (i.e. npart/ngrid) should be fixed and should be much greater than 1, in order to reduce numerical noise. The runtime needed (here in units of ω_p^−1) to observe the instability can be estimated from the maximum growth rate.

Here's the full python 3 code I am working with. Please note I have little experience with coding so I might ask lots of follow up questions. Thank you.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# 
#  Python script for computing and plotting single charged particle 
#  trajectories in prescribed electric and magnetic fields.
#  Roughly equivalent to boris.m matlab program

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import os
import os.path
import sys
from sys import exit
from time import sleep

# ===================================
#     
# Function to integrate particle trajectory
# in given E, B fields
#
# ===================================

def integrate(E0, B0, vz0):
   global dt, v0, x0, xp, yp, zp, qom, larmor, nsteps
   wc=qom*B0 # cyclotron frequency
   larmor=vperp/wc
   print ("Cyclotron frequency =",wc)
   print ("Perpendicular velocity v_p=",vperp)
   print ("Larmor radius=",larmor)

   norm = 1.  # choose whether to normalise plot axes dimensions to Larmor radius
   trun=5*2*np.pi/wc  # total runtime
   dt=.1/wc  # timestep - adjust to current B-field

   nsteps=int(trun/dt)  # timesteps
   E=np.array([0.,E0,0.])  # initial E-field
   B=np.array([0.,0.,B0])  # initial B-field
   u=np.array([0.,0.,0.])  # intermediate velocity
   h=np.array([0.,0.,0.])  # normalized B-field
   xp[0]=x0[0]
   yp[0]=x0[1]
   zp[0]=x0[2]
   v0[2]=vz0 # z-component

   v=v0+.5*dt*qom*(E+np.cross(v0,B)) # shift initial velocity back 1/2 step
   x=x0

   for itime in range(1,nsteps):
     x=x+dt*v
     xp[itime]=x[0] /norm
     yp[itime]=x[1] /norm
     zp[itime]=x[2] /norm
     tp[itime]=itime*dt
#
# Boris mover: solves dv/dt = q/m*(E + vxB) to 2nd order accuracy in dt
#
     qomdt2 = dt*qom/2
     h = qomdt2*B
     s=2*h/(1+np.dot(h,h)) 
     u = v + qomdt2*E
     up=u+np.cross(u+np.cross(u,h),s)
     v=up+qomdt2*E

#     vxp[itime] = v[0]
 

# ===================================
 
# Make 2D plots of particle orbit
#
# ===================================

def plot_track2D():
  global xp,yp,nsteps,ax1

  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8)) # initialize plot
  xmin=np.min(xp)
  xmax=np.max(xp)
  ymin=np.min(yp)
  ymax=np.max(yp)
  fig.add_subplot(221) # 1st subplot in 2x2 arrangement 
  plt.cla()
  plt.grid(True, which='both')
  plt.xlim( (xmin, xmax) )
  plt.ylim( (ymin, ymax) )
  plt.xlabel('$x$')
  plt.ylabel('$y$')
  plt.plot(xp[0:nsteps],yp[0:nsteps],c='b')

  fig.add_subplot(222) # 2nd subplot

#  fig.add_subplot(223) # 2nd subplot
#  fig.add_subplot(224) # 2nd subplot

  plt.draw()
  plt.savefig('./particle_orbit.png') # Save plot to file

# ===================================
#   
# Make 3D plot of particle orbit
#
# ===================================

def plot_track3D():
  global xp,yp,zp,nsteps,ax1
  xmin=np.min(xp)
  xmax=np.max(xp)
  ymin=np.min(yp)
  ymax=np.max(yp)
  zmin=np.min(zp)
  zmax=np.max(zp)
  ax1.cla()

  plt.ion()
  plt.grid(True, which='both')
  ax1.set_xlim( (xmin, xmax) )
  ax1.set_ylim( (ymin, ymax) )
  ax1.set_zlim( (zmin, zmax) )
  ax1.set_xlabel('$x $ [m]')
  ax1.set_ylabel('$y $ [m]')
  ax1.set_zlabel('$z $ [m]')
#ax1.set_aspect(1.)
  ax1.scatter(xp,yp,zp,c=tp,marker='o') # tracks coloured by elapsed time since start
  plt.draw()

# =============================================
#
#  Main program
#
# =============================================

print ("Charged particle orbit solver")
plotboxsize   = 8.
animated = True


x0=np.array([0.,0.,0.])     # initial coords
vz0=0.
v0=np.array([-1e2,0.,vz0]) # initial velocity
vperp = np.sqrt(v0[0]**2+v0[2]**2)
E0=0.
B0=.1

e=1.602176e-19 # electron charge
m=9.109e-31 # electron mass
qom=e/m  # charge/mass ratio

wc=qom*B0 # cyclotron frequency
larmor=vperp/wc
print (wc,vperp,larmor)

trun=5*2*np.pi/wc  # total runtime
dt=.1/wc  # timestep - adjust to current B-field

nsteps=int(trun/dt)  # timesteps
B1=np.array([0.,0.,0.1])  # gradient B perturbation

#wc=qom*np.linalg.norm(B) # cyclotron frequency

#nsteps=2
tp = np.zeros(nsteps)  # variables to store particle tracks
xp = np.zeros(nsteps)  
yp = np.zeros(nsteps) 
zp = np.zeros(nsteps)
vxp = np.zeros(nsteps) 
vyp = np.zeros(nsteps) 
vzp = np.zeros(nsteps)

# Compute orbit
integrate(E0, B0, vz0)

# 2D orbit plotter
plot_track2D()

exit(0) # Quit script before 3D plot - comment out to continue!

# Start 3D interactive mode with sliders for B, E and v0

plt.ion() # Turn on interactive plot display
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
# Get instance of Axis3D
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Get current rotation angle
print (ax1.azim)

# Set initial view to x-y plane
ax1.view_init(elev=90,azim=0)
ax1.set_xlabel('$x $[microns]')
ax1.set_ylabel('$y $[microns]')
ax1.set_zlabel('$z $[microns]')
plot_track3D()

#filename = 'a0_45/parts_p0000.%0*d'%(6, ts)
#plot_from_file(filename):
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axe0 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.95, 0.3, 0.03])#, facecolor=axcolor) # box position, color & size
axb0  = fig.add_axes([0.5, 0.95, 0.3, 0.03])#, facecolor=axcolor)
axv0  = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.9, 0.3, 0.03])#, facecolor=axcolor)

sefield = Slider(axe0, 'Ey [V/m]', -5.0,5.0, valinit=E0)
sbfield = Slider(axb0, 'Bz [T]', -1.0, 1.0, valinit=B0)
svz = Slider(axv0, 'vz [m/s]', 0.0, 1.0, valinit=0.)

def update(val):
    E0 = sefield.val
    B0 = sbfield.val
    vz0 = svz.val

    integrate(E0,B0,vz0)
    plot_track3D()
    plt.draw()

sefield.on_changed(update)
sbfield.on_changed(update)
svz.on_changed(update)

   
resetax = fig.add_axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', color=axcolor, hovercolor='0.975')
def reset(event):
    global ax1
    sefield.reset()
    sbfield.reset()
    svz.reset()
    ax1.cla()
    ax1.set_xlabel('$x $[microns]')
    ax1.set_ylabel('$y $[microns]')
    ax1.set_xlim( (0., 10.) )
#    ax1.set_ylim( (-sigma, sigma) )
    ax1.grid(True, which='both')
    plt.draw()
button.on_clicked(reset)

   
#plt.show()
plt.show(block=False)
```

$$x=3$$

Answer (score 1):

From algorithmic stability concerns there are only upper bounds on the two variables grid length and time step, dx and dt taken together. Put very informally, in one time step a particle must not travel a longer distance than from a grid cell to one of its direct neighbours. There is no lower limit on grid spacing until you come into conflict with the resolution of your numerical data type or run out of computing memory, or the time to execute one simulation run takes far too long.